# React: RadarChart in Rechart send error despite I fournish him a JSON object

Tags: reactjs, json, api, graph

I'm practicing React.js and I'm trying to display a chart about pokemon statistic using Rechart library.

I declare a state in the form of a JSON object in the state of my component. I then make a call to an API to provide the right stats corresponding to the pokemon chosen in my state.

Here is my problem, if I put hard values in my JSON object the graph is displayed correctly with these values when the app is launched. But when the values change with the API call, I get this warning in web console when the graph tries to read my different data:

```
Warning: Received NaN for the `x1` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string.
    in line (created by PolarRadiusAxis)
    in g (created by Layer)
    in Layer (created by PolarRadiusAxis)
    in PolarRadiusAxis (at CompetenceChartPokemon.js:159)
    in svg (created by Surface)
    in Surface (created by RadarChart)
    in div (created by RadarChart)
    in RadarChart (at CompetenceChartPokemon.js:149)

Warning: Received NaN for the `y1` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string.
    in line (created by PolarRadiusAxis)
    in g (created by Layer)
    in Layer (created by PolarRadiusAxis)
    in PolarRadiusAxis (at CompetenceChartPokemon.js:159)
    in svg (created by Surface)
    in Surface (created by RadarChart)
    in div (created by RadarChart)
    in RadarChart (at CompetenceChartPokemon.js:149)
             ... same error for each of the axis
```

And my graph is totally empty, I just see line which represent each axis of the graph.

To solve this problem I took the rendering of my graph out of my render function, indeed my call to the API is asynchronous and so I think that my data may not have been all retrieved at the time of the call to create the graph.

But when I display my state in the form of a JSON in the web console it has the right values.
I was told that console.log() could take a long time to run and therefore it would show me the right values in my console while the graph call which is faster did not have all this data yet but it seems strange to me.

I put a part of my code here,

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import {
    Radar,
    RadarChart,
    PolarGrid,
    PolarAngleAxis,
    PolarRadiusAxis
} from "recharts";

class CompetenceChartPokemon extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            statistic: [
                {
                    subject: "Hp",
                    pokemonStat: 100 //I've put hard value for the 3 first stat to see if they were displaying at launch of app and they are displaying
                },
                {
                    subject: "Attack",
                    pokemonStat: 123
                },
                {
                    subject: "Defense",
                    pokemonStat: 345
                },
                {
                    subject: "Special Attack",
                    pokemonStat: 0
                },
                {
                    subject: "Special Defense",
                    pokemonStat: 0
                },
                {
                    subject: "Speed",
                    pokemonStat: 0
                }
            ],
            pokemonChosen: false,
            pokemonLoading: true,
            pokemonColorAPI: "",
            pokemonIdAPI: "",
            pokemonNameAPI: "",
        };
    }

    handlePokemonNameChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ pokemonName: e.target.value });
        this.setState({ pokemonChosen: true });
    }

    searchPokemon = () => {
        this.setState({ pokemonLoading: true });
        Axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/getPokemon/pokemonStat/${this.state.pokemonName}`)
            .then(res => {
                if (res.status === 200 && res != null) {
                    let copyJSONArray = this.state.statistic.slice();

                    res.data.stats.map((stat, index) => {
                        copyJSONArray[index] = stat.base_stat;
                    })

                    this.setState({ statistic: copyJSONArray });

                    this.setState({ pokemonIdAPI: res.data.id }); // here I get id of pokemon for a second API call which will give me color of pokemon (info not available in first call)

                    this.setState({ pokemonNameAPI: res.data.name });

                    console.log(res);

                    Axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/getPokemon/pokemonNameFr/${this.state.pokemonIdAPI}`)
                        .then(response => {
                            if (response.status === 200 && response != null) {
                                this.setState({ pokemonColorAPI: response.data.color.name });
                            } else {
                                console.log('problem in second call');
                            }
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.log(error);
                        });

                    this.setState({ pokemonLoading: false });
                } else {
                    console.log('problem in first call');
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        console.log(this.state.statistic);  //this state is filling correctly here
    }

    renderGraph() {
        let color = "";
        if (this.state.pokemonColorAPI === "black") {
            color = "#1D2525";
        }
        if (this.state.pokemonColorAPI === "blue") {
            color = "#2350B8";
        }
        if (this.state.pokemonColorAPI === "brown") {
            color = "#904F17";
        }
        if (this.state.pokemonColorAPI === "gray") {
            color = "#999999";
        }
        if (this.state.pokemonColorAPI === "green") {
            color = "#438A3B";
        }
        if (this.state.pokemonColorAPI === "pink") {
            color = "#FFB7CE";
        }
        if (this.state.pokemonColorAPI === "purple") {
            color = "#8D5E9B"
        }
        if (this.state.pokemonColorAPI === "red") {
            color = "#BB4B49";
        }
        if (this.state.pokemonColorAPI === "white") {
            color = "#F0EEFF";
        }
        if (this.state.pokemonColorAPI === "yellow") {
            color = "#FFF380";
        }

        if (this.state.pokemonNameAPI === undefined) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return (<React.Fragment>
                {console.log(this.state.statistic)}
                <RadarChart
                    cx={300}
                    cy={250}
                    outerRadius={150}
                    width={500}
                    height={500}
                    data={this.state.statistic}
                >
                    <PolarGrid />
                    <PolarAngleAxis dataKey="subject" />
                    <PolarRadiusAxis />
                    <Radar
                        name={this.state.pokemonName}
                        dataKey="pokemonStat"
                        stroke="#8884d8"
                        fill="#8884d8"
                        fillOpacity={0.6}
                    />
                </RadarChart>
            </React.Fragment>
            )
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="DisplayOnePokemon">
                <div className="TitleSection">
                    <h1>Pokemon Stats</h1>
                    <input type="text" onChange={this.handlePokemonNameChange} value={this.state.pokemonName} />
                    <button onClick={this.searchPokemon}>Search Pokemon stats graph</button>
                </div>
                <div className="DisplaySection">
                    {((!this.state.pokemonChosen) && (this.state.pokemonLoading == false)) ? (
                        <h1>Please choose a Pokemon</h1>
                    ) : (
                        <div>{this.renderGraph()}</div>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div >
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the link to the documentation of the graph I am trying to use  https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/SimpleRadarChart, I don't understand what I am doing wrong compared to the example given in the doc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work, the problem was with my JSON state declaration in my constructor replacing it with an array and creating a JSON const in my renderGraph method that takes the values from my array worked.